# Android Eclipse ADT device configuration for EVO 4G 4.3" layout

Tags: android, configuration, layout, config, adt

I'm trying to create an ADT layout configuration to match an EVO 4G screen, with its 800x480 resolution and 4.3" screen. The emulator I created by just specifying WVGA800 in the SDK Manager seems to match my physical EVO device perfectly.

However, when I try to create a Layout device config (the one you select when you edit an XML view), I can't match it at all, no matter the values I've tried so far. The default configuration only includes a 3.7" and then jumps to 5.1" (whaaa, why did ADT devs think 4.3" screens weren't important enough?). OK, so I make a custom one, but no matter what values I try, I can't match the emulator size.

Does anyone know what the exact values I must put in to the layout config for it to match 100%? x dpi, y dpi? Values I found online end up not matching the right size. It looks like the Density needs to be set to High, and Screen Ratio and Screen Size don't matter.

Thank you.

Comment: The layout designer should be taken with a grain of salt. It doesn't matter what layout you use. It should work for all phones. I purposely use an emaulator different from my real phone.

Comment: I realize that and want to test on many different configurations, but should matching my real phone be this big of a task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artem - I have the same phone, and the same problem as you.  I played around a bit, and I found that setting the x and y dpis to 250 is a pretty good match (with dpi set to "high density").  I doubt it is 100%, but it is close enough for me for now.

If anyone else has found a better value, please post it.